# CSS transform scale to background image

Tags: css, background-image, transform, scale

I have beloved CSS part effecting for a image

```
.split-banner .right-cl:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

I need to apply above CSS to background image contain in a div element
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `background-size` on hover. To mimic `scale(1.1)` use `110%`.

```css
div {
  width: 560px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url('http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png') center center no-repeat;
}
div:hover {
  background-size: 110%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if I want to apply a transition *only on the background* like `-webkit-transition: transform 5.05s ease-in-out;` any idea?

Comment: @OlivierPons can you apply your background and transition styles to a pseudo element (`::before`, `::after`) of the element you're working with?