# Javascript zoom in/out to mouse x/y coordinates

Tags: javascript, css, zooming, scale

I managed to make the mouse dragging to scroll the div, but the zooming in/out with the mouse is not complete.

It works, but I would like for the mouse pointer to hold the image in that position and scale it at the same time, like so:

[image: Screenshot]

I need to use `scrollBy()` to return the scrolling back to the previous point before scaling. Anyone knows how to do that?

This is a fiddle made by someone https://jsfiddle.net/xta2ccdt/13/ and it's exactly what I need, but the code uses `translate()` and other things which don't apply here, since I have scrolling/dragging too.

Here's my jsfiddle code https://jsfiddle.net/catalinu/1f6e0jna/

And here's the code in stackoverflow:

Please help. I struggled with this for days.

```js
for (const divMain of document.getElementsByClassName('main')) {
  // drag the section
  for (const divSection of divMain.getElementsByClassName('section')) {
   // when mouse is pressed store the current mouse x,y
    let previousX, previousY
    divSection.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
      previousX = event.pageX
      previousY = event.pageY
    })
    
    // when mouse is moved, scrollBy() the mouse movement x,y
    divSection.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
     // only do this when the primary mouse button is pressed (event.buttons = 1)
      if (event.buttons) {
        let dragX = 0
        let dragY = 0
        // skip the drag when the x position was not changed
        if (event.pageX - previousX !== 0) {
          dragX = previousX - event.pageX
          previousX = event.pageX
        }
        // skip the drag when the y position was not changed
        if (event.pageY - previousY !== 0) {
          dragY = previousY - event.pageY
          previousY = event.pageY
        }
        // scrollBy x and y
        if (dragX !== 0 || dragY !== 0) {
          divMain.scrollBy(dragX, dragY)
        }
      }
    })
  }

  // zoom in/out on the section
  let scale = 1
  const scaleFactor = 0.05
  divMain.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
   // preventDefault to stop the onselectionstart event logic
    event.preventDefault()
    for (const divSection of divMain.getElementsByClassName('section')) {
     // set the scale change value
      const scaleChange = (event.deltaY < 0) ? scaleFactor : -scaleFactor
      // don't allow the scale to go outside of [0,5 - 2]
      if (scale + scaleChange < 0.5 || scale + scaleChange > 2) {
        return
      }
      // round the value when using high dpi monitors
      scale = Math.round((scale + scaleChange) * 100) / 100

   // apply the css scale
      divSection.style.transform = `scale(${scale}, ${scale})`

      // re-adjust the scrollbars        
      const x = Math.round(divMain.scrollLeft * scaleChange)
      const y = Math.round(divMain.scrollTop * scaleChange)
      divMain.scrollBy(x, y)
    }
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
 width: 100%; /* percentage fixes the X axis white space when zoom out */
 height: 100vh; /* this is still an issue where you see white space when zoom out in the Y axis */
 overflow: scroll; /* needed for safari to show the x axis scrollbar */
}

.main .section {
 width: 200%;
 height: 200vh;
 background-image: url('https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/big-one.jpg');
 transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <section class="section"></section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You issue is mostly around the below lines

```js
const x = Math.round(divMain.scrollLeft * scaleChange)
const y = Math.round(divMain.scrollTop * scaleChange)
```

The way scroll with scale works like below

- Calculate the unscaled `x, y` coordinate where zoom happens
- Calculate the new scaled `x, y` coordinate my multiplying it with the new scale
- Now you want this new coordinate remain at the same place where the existing coordinate was. So basically if you subtract the `offset x,y` from the new `scaled x,y`, you get the scroll left and top.

The updated code is like below

```js
for (const divMain of document.getElementsByClassName('main')) {
  // drag the section
  for (const divSection of divMain.getElementsByClassName('section')) {
    // when mouse is pressed store the current mouse x,y
    let previousX, previousY
    divSection.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
      previousX = event.pageX
      previousY = event.pageY
    })

    // when mouse is moved, scrollBy() the mouse movement x,y
    divSection.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
        // only do this when the primary mouse button is pressed (event.buttons = 1)
      if (event.buttons) {
        let dragX = 0
        let dragY = 0
        // skip the drag when the x position was not changed
        if (event.pageX - previousX !== 0) {
          dragX = previousX - event.pageX
          previousX = event.pageX
        }
        // skip the drag when the y position was not changed
        if (event.pageY - previousY !== 0) {
          dragY = previousY - event.pageY
          previousY = event.pageY
        }
        // scrollBy x and y
        if (dragX !== 0 || dragY !== 0) {
          divMain.scrollBy(dragX, dragY)
        }
      }
    })
  }

  // zoom in/out on the section
  let scale = 1
  const factor = 0.05
  const max_scale =4

  divMain.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
    // preventDefault to stop the onselectionstart event logic
    for (const divSection of divMain.getElementsByClassName('section')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var delta = e.delta || e.wheelDelta;
        if (delta === undefined) {
          //we are on firefox
          delta = e.originalEvent.detail;
        }
        delta = Math.max(-1,Math.min(1,delta)) // cap the delta to [-1,1] for cross browser consistency
            offset = {x: divMain.scrollLeft, y: divMain.scrollTop};
     image_loc = {
        x: e.pageX + offset.x,
        y: e.pageY + offset.y
     }

     zoom_point = {x:image_loc.x/scale, y: image_loc.y/scale}

        // apply zoom
        scale += delta*factor * scale
        scale = Math.max(1,Math.min(max_scale,scale))

     zoom_point_new = {x:zoom_point.x * scale, y: zoom_point.y * scale}

     newScroll = {
        x: zoom_point_new.x - e.pageX,
        y: zoom_point_new.y - e.pageY
     }


      divSection.style.transform = `scale(${scale}, ${scale})`
      divMain.scrollTop = newScroll.y
      divMain.scrollLeft = newScroll.x
    }


  })
}
```

The updated fiddle is

https://jsfiddle.net/uy390v8t/1/

[image: Results]

Comment: Thank you. This indeed fixed the scrolling. I have applied your changes to my code here https://jsfiddle.net/catalinu/zof8q63u/15/ and I have also fixed the white space at the bottom when zooming out at maximum. Need to wait 18 hours to give you the bounty too.

Comment: Using your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/catalinu/jLfrbzwp/ and changing the min scale to 0.5, do you know why when you zoom out at 0.5, why is the vertical scrollbar that big and scrolling down reveals a lot of white space? Any way to fix it?

Comment: That happens because you have given a fixed `200vh` height, the height also needs to be set through javascript to make sure it is what you want it to be

Comment: I have added a fixed width and height of 5000px to the section div like so https://jsfiddle.net/catalinu/jLfrbzwp/2/ . What width/height do I need to set with javascript since it will always stay the same, only the scaling changes? Shouldn't the browser figure that out? The horizontal side works cause the main container is 100%, but the vertical side breaks with that white space because we use 100vh, since 100% height doesn't do anything. Any solutions?

Comment: I would suggest to post a new question for this. Also see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616579/css-transform-scale-to-background-image ? Also post the link to your new question in this thread for reference

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57373062/cross-browser-height-100-on-transform-scale-1