# Cross-browser height 100% on transform scale <1

Tags: css, scroll, safari, css-transforms

I can't seem to find a way to make the height of the child container to be 100% of the parent and just see scrollbars. Instead we see double the amount of white space for the height.

This question is related to [Javascript zoom in/out to mouse x/y coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262208/javascript-zoom-in-out-to-mouse-x-y-coordinates)

If we don't have `overflow` set in the main container then in

- Chrome works
- Safari = works, but we don't have an x-axis scrollbar
- Firefox = white space issue

If we set `overflow: auto or scroll` then in

- Chrome = white space issue
- Safari = we have the scrollbar, but still the white space issue
- Firefox = white space issue

We need the overflow property to make safari show the scrollbars, which add the white space issue on all browsers.

JSfiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/catalinu/jLfrbzwp/4/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
 width: 100%; /* percentage fixes the X axis white space */
 height: 100vh; /* i would love to use 100% but it doesn't work for height */
 overflow: scroll; /* needed for safari to show the x axis scrollbar */
}

.main .section {
 width: 2000px;
 height: 2000px;
 background-color: #333;
 transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <section class="section"></section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But the transform's visual part get's proper sizing when using width 100% for the main container. If we change the width to 100vw, we will see the same issue that we have with the height. So how can we `help` the height to work with this?

Comment: okay, i have no safari , so i cannot fully rproduce your issue, did you check if  `backface-visibility:hidden;`  would solve uor issue ? . Chrome (and eventually safari) had by the past annoying bugs with transform. https://jsfiddle.net/Lpawf9du/ (add prefix if needed)

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changes in any of the browser (Chrome Windows, Firefox Windows, Safari Mac). There's also a js fiddle link in the main question for you to test things.

Comment: what do you mean, nothing change ? do you talk about the 1000px white space aside and below section that shows ?

Comment: I mean, the height is doubled with 1000px from the grey child container and another 1000px from the parent white background. Correctly we should see only the grey child container and no white space from the parent.

Comment: Is this what you expected ? https://jsfiddle.net/pcy7qdz5/ if so, it was my first comment, your box ups or dowscaled, will always be it's original size and at its original position in the flow of the document. transform only happens at screen.

Comment: Yes, but we need the `overflow` in the main container to make safari show the x-axis scrollbar.

Comment: okay, i'll leave it here , i cannot help about safari

Comment: The ` backface-visibility` doesn't really do anything, and neither does `margin-right`, but the `margin-bottom:- 1000px` does fix the issue. But this looks more like a hack and the `margin-bottom` will have to be set with javascript dynamically, since the scaling will change (check the related question). Interesting fix, thanks. I'm still waiting for a proper fix without js hacks.